# Error org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

i have a problem with rest and method post on my controler i have this 2 class the first is user in my class user i have my class with the getters and setter and a default contructor because for the finally I would like use Hibernate .:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Utilisateur") // mapping with hibernate (but not using in this situation)
public class User {

    @Id
    private long id;
    @Column(name="nom")
    private String nom;
    @Column(name="prenom")
    private String prenom;
    @Column(name="admin")
    private boolean admin;
    @Column(name="actif")
    private boolean actif;
    @Column(name="logins")
    private String logins;
    @Column(name="email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name="naissance")
    private String naissance;
    @Column(name="pwd")
    private String pwd;
    @Column(name="compte")
    private String compte;

    public User(){

    }
    /*
     with getter and setter.
    */
}
```

and my class controler (User controller) :  is using for make the api principally post api .

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping(
        value="/api/greetings/post",
            method = RequestMethod.POST,
            consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
    )
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<User> getByEmail(@RequestBody User user){
        if(user==null){

            return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(user, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

and i get this erreur  I am using postman for make the query and in parameter of my query I send this Json query :

```
{"id":"3","nom":"Gille","prenom":"Laurent","admin":"1","actif":"0","logins":"gilaur","email":""toto@hotmail.com,"naissance":"1990/09/09","pwd":"gal","compte":"autre"}
```

And i get this error :

```
{"timestamp":1457906727481,"status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException","message":"Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported","path":"/api/greetings/post/"}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

you are change headers content-type `application/json` in Postman because you try set `text/plain`

Comment: Thank you  but when i am using your method i get the same error but when i delete the @RequestBody i get this.

Comment: {"id":0,"nom":null,"prenom":null,"admin":false,"actif":false,"logins":null,"email":null,"naissance":null,"pwd":null,"compte":null}

Comment: dont delete @RequestBody  try your example again but your email is not in " " bracket did you see this   "email":""toto@hotmail.com

Comment: and use this example to sent by  postman  {"id":"3","nom":"Gille","prenom":"Laurent","admin":"true","actif":"true","logins":"gilaur",
"email":"toto@hotmail.com","naissance":"1990/09/09","pwd":"gal","compte":"autre"}

Comment: Thank you But on postman i don't use bracket for the parameters and i get the same result.

Comment: do you also send requestbody raw and Json ?

Comment: Thank you i send the response  i got {"id":0,"nom":null,"prenom":null,"admin":false,"actif":false,"logins":null,"email":null,"naissance":null,"pwd":null,"compte":null} but i don't understand why

Comment: I put in the parameters this : {"nom":"Gille","prenom":"Laurent","admin":"true","actif":"true","logins":"gilaur","email":"toto@hotmail.com","naissance":"1990/09/09","pwd":"gal","compte":"autre"} , The question is i must use the hearder and in the same time the request with the json text ? thanks

Comment: Http post means upload and you must configure your data also type is your choice for example json,xml,text,img ... etc,Content type is notice your data type and the suggestion stating that it will improve in applications                    if your problem solved  , please confirm my answer

Comment: I try to fix the problem

Comment: if you not add content type in request  you get error "Unsupported Media Type" because you point  @RequestBody User user  and you try sent text  and text is String type  your code not incorrect you try to sent bad data type because code not resolve this data by User.class pojo